# Why isn't the staff of the TVA better armed？

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, loki-2021, time-variance-authority

The TVA is extremely powerful: they have Infinity Stones and incredible technology. If these Infinity Stones contain a full set of six, then the TVA should be omniscient and omnipotent, at least in one universe. They can create anything they want in that universe and bring it back to the TVA office, for further use. If not, consider their position, any technology that has ever been invented in history should contain no secret to them. In short, anything the ordinary human/alien/gods have, the TVA can have.

However, during the chasing of "evil Loki", one team was burned by the oil fires and another wounded by spear and knife. It is hard to accept that the members of the most powerful organization are vulnerable to ordinary fire and cold weapons. I mean, why doesn't the TVA make some fire-proof, knife-proof, bullet-proof Stark-Tech super suits for their teams? This can be very easily done.

Comment: That all sounds very expensive.

Comment: I don't have time to answer now so I'll leave a comment here. Most of the TVA's job is resetting branches and the picture we're shown is a lot of that doesn't involve combat. On top of that their equipment is very high level, it's the protection that isn't great. However, there are trade offs between better protection (and of what type) and manoeuvrability etc. You can't prepare for every eventuality and an ambush usually goes in favour of a well prepared attacker anyway.

Comment: *"then the TVA should be omniscient and omnipotent"* - If they had an Infinity Gauntlet....but they don't.

Comment: @Paulie_D They might, just cos we're not shown one doesn't mean they don't have one. Also you can use the Stones outside of the gauntlet. So presumably there would be a way of using all outside of it. The Gauntlet just makes it easier to use them.

Comment: The infinity stones don’t have any power. In fact, no magic has any power whatsoever.

Comment: @OKprogrammer at the TVA but the question is framed about the Minutemen when in the Sacred Timeline I believe.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Good thought. My personal theory is that the TVA can’t have extremely powerful weapons in action due to the possible significance of damage they could wreck, such as creating a crater or some other issue, which could mess up the timeline.

Comment: @OKprogrammer has it right. It’s the Sacred Timeline, not the Go And Wreak Whatever Cosmic Havoc We Want Timeline. The TVA are there to maintain history. An Infinity Stone is what allowed our Loki to create a new timeline; taking them into timelines they’re trying to erase sounds way more risky than is worth it. They already have grenades that erase time; until this Loki Variant showed up, that was all they needed.

Comment: Why doesn't every FBI agent wear bullet proof vests and helmets and boots, etc? Because their job isn't to fight, it's to investigate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Think about it from a risk standpoint. Although using the most advanced and powerful weapons would definitely make neutralizing the variant easier, it could cause extreme damage in certain scenarios.

### Scenario One:

**The weapons are too powerful.**

Let’s say the TVA decide to use a futuristic alien weapon. Although it might destroy the variant, there is an extremely large charge chance that the damage caused by the weapon might be too extreme to be repaired in the short amount of time before the timeline reaches the red zone.

### Scenario Two:

**The variant steals the weapon.**

In an alternate scenario, let’s say that the TVA has decided to use the infinity gauntlet as the weapon of choice against the variant. Although the chances of success are essentially 100%, if the variant managed to somehow get the gauntlet, the results would be catastrophic and most likely result in a Nexus Event.

So, it makes sense that the TVA would try to use weapons that are decently powerful and work against virtually all variants with minimal damage, instead of taking the risk.

Comment: Does it make sense to repair something from a timeline that you are going to destroy?

Comment: @alseether: My understanding is they considered it only "Resetting" the timeline - it'll still continue, just without the variance from the variant, and be closer to the regular timeline.

Answer (score 8):

### The TVA is perfectly equipped for their primary function

**"Better" is a bad word to use to describe more destructive firepower.** Their technology and weaponry appear to be well - if not perfectly - suited for policing and restoring the timeline.

A few key points to consider that affect what equipment and manpower are appropriate:

- The TVA believes the Time Keepers' timeline is sacred and they're extremely careful not to affect the timeline when they're in the field.
- Ranged and area-of-effect weapons like traditional firearms, grenades, bombs, etc. have a tendency to be imprecise and have a high likelihood of causing collateral damage.
- Mystical/super-powered/cosmic weaponry has enough hand-waivy ability to be both precise and highly destructive but is completely ineffective outside the normal time stream. Variants would become EXTREMELY dangerous once they're apprehended and brought to TVA headquarters.
- In the field, the most immediate need is apprehending or "pruning" the variant and then "pruning" anything else in the vicinity that may contribute to a nexus event without causing a nexus event yourself.

Specifically referring to the Infinity Stones, while access to stones isn't an issue, wielding them requires an immense amount of power which is why only a few in the universe can do so - and even then, most require some sort of conduit like the Infinity Gauntlet or Loki's scepter so they don't have to touch them directly - without being killed by the power (like Tony Stark). TVA officers don't appear to have that kind of power. Even if they did, the stones - and therefore the officers - become completely useless back at headquarters.

**Based on the points outlined above, equipment such as the restraints, localized time loop controls, pruning batons, and pruning bombs that we've already seen sound perfectly precise and effective at handling typical variant threats. For larger threats, sending more officers/detectives makes more sense, not stronger firepower.**

Comment: I don't think they're extremely careful in the slightest.  They show up in 17th century Salem with clothes and gear that are decidedly anachronistic.  They show up everywhere and everywhen that way.  They barely care at all by the very conceit of their being there to prune the divergent timeline.  Any concern they do have would seem to be limited entirely to making sure it doesn't redline before they prune it, or of not creating a divergent timeline when Loki is allowed to experiment in a non-divergent timeline.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy - Their outfits are definitely an inconsistency but the fact that they care so much about avoiding a redline event only further illustrates my point. While other time travel stories depict local reactions to main characters' futuristic wardrobe as detrimental to the timeline, this one clearly doesn't.

Comment: It's a a self-correcting situation:  If the timeline get pruned in time then all the witnesses cease to exist so there is nothing to worry about. If they run a timeline past the red line *then* suddenly their gear is anachronistic. Another reason to worry about redlining.